# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} v_n$ where $\lim_{n \to \infty} v_n = 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose we have a real non-negative sequence $(v_n)$ where $\lim_{n \to \infty} v_n = 0$. Does the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} v_n$ always converge? If not, in which cases is the series convergent? I asked this myself but don't find any answers

Thanks very much

Comment: What about $v_{n} = 1_{\left\{n,n+1,n+2,...\right\}}$ i.e the charactheristic function of the set of all natural numbers $k\geq n$

Comment: You may be interested in [this MathOverflow question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/49415/nonexistence-of-boundary-between-convergent-and-divergent-series).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $v_1=0$, and for $n\ge 2$ let $v_n=\frac{1}{\ln n}$.  Then $v_n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Note that by the Integral Test the series $\sum_2^\infty \frac{1}{n\ln n}$ diverges. So the condition $v_n\to 0$ is not sufficient to ensure the convergence of $\sum_1^\infty \frac{v_n}{n}$.